# Can we play 2 videos simultaneously in windows phone 7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, video

Can we play 2 videos simultaneously in windows phone 7 application.

I am using 2 media elements in 1 xaml page. But only one of the videos is getting displayed. How can I play videos. Please suggest some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use only one MediaElement on a page. please refer [MediaElement Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202883%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) First.

The reason you are seeing on video is because when we use MediaElement, all other playing audio video are stops.

The answer how can you play two videos using MediaElement or another option is CompositionTarget.Rendering Event.
CompositionTarget.Rendering actually renders a frame.
For details visit [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748838.aspx).

Code in XAML

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <StackPanel>
            <MediaElement Name="ME1" Source="/Images/oceansclip1.mp4" Stretch="Fill" AutoPlay="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="250"/>
            <MediaElement Name="ME2" Source="/Images/oceansclip2.mp4" Stretch="Fill" AutoPlay="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10" Height="250"/>
            <Button Content="Play" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Code behind XAML

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTarget_Rendering1;
    }

    private void CompositionTarget_Rendering1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mediaElement1.Play();
        mediaElement2.Play();
    }
```

But CompositionTarget.Rendering do not guarantee time between the calls, so you may get frames running faster or slower.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But this till doesnot solve my problem. On click of Play button, only one video is getting played and not the other one. Also again on clicking the button, same video is getting played.

Comment: What I want is, when the page gets loaded, 2 videos should start playing simultaneously on 1 screen, one below the other. How to do that. Please provide some more suggestions.

Comment: You want to use only MediaElement?

Comment: anything will work, i have just used mediaElement for playing vedios thats why was asking for the same. But i can use any other option also if available.